# python call function with argument as user input in dictionary?

Tags: python, function, dictionary, arguments

I have a dictionary

```
d={}
```

User Input

```
no=raw_input("Enter number: ")
x=raw_input("Enter string: ")
y=raw_input("Enter string: ")
z=raw_input("Enter string: ")



d[no]=send(x,y,z)

def send(x,y,z):
    print x,y,z
```

Is this possible?

I tried but when I print dictionary, it outputs

```
{1: None}
```

I want output something like this

```
 d{
    1:send(x,y,z),
    2:send(x,y,z),
    3:send(x,y,z)
  }
```

where x,y,z are user input.

Comment: And what would `send()` need to *return* in this case?

Comment: what do you want to store with `send` : the function, the tuple, other stuff ?

Comment: Your function doesn't *return* anything, which means the default is returned instead, `None`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `send` function doesn't make sense. You can just do:

```
d[no] = (x,y,z)
```

If you want to assign and print to console, then I guess you can have:

```
d[no] = send(x,y,z)

def send(x,y,z):
    print x,y,z
    return x,y,z
```

But this is rather strange.

Answer (score 1):

Use `return` instead of `print`:

```
def send(x,y,z):
    return x, y, z
```

You'll get:

```
d = {
    1: (x, y, z)
    2: (x, y, z)
    3: (x, y, z)
}
```

If you literally want to see `"send(x, y, z)"` in the dictionary use:

```
def send(x,y,z):
    return "send({0}, {1}, {2})".format(x, y, z)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just return the value instead of printing it.

```
def send(x, y, z):
    return x, y, z
```